# Is it valid according the FIDE chess rule?

Tags: online-chess, castling, online-blitz, lichess

From [FIDE Law of Chess, article 3.8](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=171&view=article), it is stated as:
[image: Castling Rule]

Now, coming to [My game vs killin_pieces on lichess.org](https://lichess.org/PAXCH1gQ) :

After move 9, situation was something like this: b1 was threatened by my opponent's light square bishop:

[image: position 9]

Still I was able to give him a discovered check on move no. 10.

[image: position 2]

which clearly contradicts FIDE Law of chess article 3.8.2.a, stated as :

> Castling is prevented temporarily: 
>   if the square on which the king stands, or **the square which it must cross**, or the square which it is to occupy, is attacked by one or more of the opponent's pieces

Can anyone please explain me how can this be possible ?

Comment: This is not a *discovered* check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The king does not cross b1 (only the rook does). It also does not end up standing on b1 following the castling. Hence, the quoted rule is not violated.